# bash - zip multiple files, take argument from variable, one of them has space in name

Tags: bash, variables, tar, quotation-marks

I want to zip `file.txt` and `file with spaces.txt`. I need to keep them in one variable. I can concat these string like this:

```
files="$files \"$newfilename\""
```

Then I have all the file names in one variable, separated by space and each one covered with quotation marks. "file.txt" "file with spaces.txt"

so I need to zip them now.
However If I do:

```
tar czf output $files
```

then bash will produce:

```
tar czf output '"file.txt."' '"file' with 'spaces.txt"'
```

If I do

```
tar czf output "$files"
```

then bash will do:

```
tar czf output '"file.txt." "file with spaces.txt"'
```

In first case, bash insert a apostrophe after and before each word, in the second case, tar takes both files as one name. What should I do to produce `tar czf "file.txt" "file with spaces.txt"` if I have exactly this string in `$files` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a variable for storing multi word entries that are independent. Use an array and quote the file-names properly, so the names with spaces are preserved

```
declare -a files=()
files=("file.txt")
files+=("file with spaces.txt")
```

The `+=()` is used to append elements to an existing array. Now expanding the array is what you need to pass the list to `zip`

```
tar czf output "${files[@]}"
```

---

Regarding OP's question on the context between doing `files=()` and `declare -a files=()`. They are probably the same thing and work in the same context of initializing indexed arrays. But a noticeable difference happens when you do `declare -a files` without the `()` part. Because `declare -a` does *not* re-initialize an array which is already defined but `=()` empties it. Refer to the example below

```
prompt> files=()
prompt> files+=(a "new word")
prompt> files+=("another word")
prompt> echo "${files[@]}"
a new word another word
```

Now doing `files=()` would empty the existing the array completely,

```
prompt> files=()                   # array completely emptied now
prompt> echo "${files[@]}"
                                   # empty result
```

But with the same content as previously and doing

```
prompt> echo "${files[@]}"
a new word another word
prompt> declare -a files           # an existing array is not emptied
prompt> echo "${files[@]}"
a new word another word
```